# Can you (now? Swift5?) write "if case" as a boolean when determining an enum's associated type?

Tags: swift5

Say you need to determine the actual associated type of an enum.

So, a situation like

```
enum MessageItem: Decodable {

    case a(Images)
    case b(Text)
    case c(Reply)
    ...
}
```

I used to have code like this

```
       xSome = x.filter {
            switch $0 {
            case .a(_):
                return false
            case .b(_):
                return true
            case .c(_):
                return true
            }
        }
```

But then it was possible to have code like this

```
       xSome = x.filter {
            if case .a = $0 { return false }
            return true
        }
```

Is there now some way it Swift to compare against associated type producing a boolean?

So, something like:

```
       xSome = x.filter {
            return (case .a = $0)
        }
```

So, something like `anEnum.is( .someCase )`

Is anything like this now in Swift?

(Naturally, I mean without adding a var in the enum, which of course you can do.)

Comment: You can say `anEnum == .someCase`. What's the situation where that won't do? If it because what you really want to compare is the associated value? Then you can say `anEnum == .someCaseWithAssociatedValue(theValueToTestAgainst)`. Enums are equatable if you declare them Equatable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enums with associated values are equatable if you declare them Equatable. Here's the state of play:

```
enum MyEnum : Equatable {
    case hey
    case ho
    case heyNonnyNo(String)
}
let e = MyEnum.hey
e == .hey // true
e == .ho // false
// e == .heyNonnyNo // blap, illegal

let e2 = MyEnum.heyNonnyNo("hello")
e2 == .heyNonnyNo("hello") // true
e2 == .heyNonnyNo("goodbye") // true
```

Why is `e == .heyNonnyNo` illegal? Because it's unclear what it can mean. This case has an associated value; its value *is* the associated value. So we can check whether two instances of this case have the same associated value, but we can't just ask (using `==`) whether an instance is *some* associated value of this case.

So if *that's* what we want to know, we are back to `if case`:

```
if case .heyNonnyNo = e2 {
    print("it's a hey nonny no")
}
```

But you can't say that without `if` (for use in a conditional) because `if case` is the keyword; `case` can't exist by itself. If you really need a Bool, you could write it out like this:

```
let ok : Bool = {
    switch e2 {
    case .heyNonnyNo: return true
    default: return false
    }
}()
```

Comment: ahhh!  "if case" is a keyword; that's a great fact

Comment: To prove that `if case` is the keyword, try wrapping everything _after_ `if` in parentheses. You can't. The word `case` is not the start of a Boolean expression. — I'm not saying your idea is a bad idea, not at all; I'm just describing the state of the language.

Comment: Right on, awesome info.  Yeah I realize the question wasn't explicit enough, I edited it. Looks like "if case" is the state of the art!!  It is somewhat strange there isn't something along the lines of `anEnum.isCase( .someCase )` ; maybe in the future.